# Oracle DB - how to display privs across schemas/owners?

Tags: database, oracle, privileges

I have a owner A and owner B in the DB. Each of them has its own schemas, etc. If I grant rights to an user from B (so he has e.g. access to some view under A), is there any way how to display privs like this? I mean, one user has some rights under each DB owner and its schematas.
The reason for that is that I would need to be sure that no user under B has access to any object under A.
Thank you very much

**EDIT: For more clear question:**

```
Sceham owner A               Schema owner B
Table X                      Table CC
Table Y                      Table DD
View Z                       View EE
```

Now say user John has access to schemas under owner A but also to one view under schema owned by Oracle owner B. How could I list his rights across schemas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle a user is a schema (USER=SCHEMA).

You can query the dictionary table `DBA_TAB_PRIVS` to see what users/roles have access to. Alternatively, if you're connected as user A, querying `USER_TAB_PRIVS` will let you see which users/roles have access to your objects (tables, procedures, packages, etc...).

If any privilege is given to a role, check `DBA_ROLE_PRIVS` to see which user is granted this role.

Lastly, check `DBA_SYS_PRIVS` to see if some global privilege is granted to a user/role. Most global privileges have `ANY` in there name (`SELECT ANY TABLE`, `EXECUTE ANY PROCEDURE`...). Global privileges take precedence over individual privileges and may let you access either directly or indirectly data accross all schemas.

---

This gets a little more complicated since a role can be granted to another role. This query will list all objects from schema A accessible to user JOHN:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table_name, PRIVILEGE
  FROM dba_tab_privs
 WHERE owner = 'A'
   AND (grantee = 'JOHN' OR
       grantee IN (SELECT dr.granted_role
                      FROM dba_role_privs dr
                     START WITH grantee = 'JOHN'
                    CONNECT BY PRIOR dr.granted_role = dr.grantee))
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use one of the DBA views to do this.

```
select privilege
       , table_name 
from dba_tab_privs
where grantee = 'B'
and owner = 'A'
/
```

If you use roles then you may also want to check that:

```
select r.granted_role
       , p.privilege
       , p.table_name
from dba_role_privs r
     join dba_tab_privs p
     on r.granted_role = p.grantee
where r.grantee = 'B'
and p.owner = 'A'
/
```

---

> "How could I list his rights across
>   schemas?"

Like this:

```
select owner
       , privilege
       , table_name 
from dba_tab_privs
where grantee = 'JOHN'
and owner IN ( 'A', 'B' )
order by owner, table_name
/
```

You might want to omit the filter on OWNER.  A similar tweak on the second query will give you granted roles across schemas.

```
select r.granted_role
       , p.privilege
       , p.table_name
from dba_role_privs r
     join dba_tab_privs p
     on r.granted_role = p.grantee
where r.grantee = 'JOHN'
and p.owner in ( 'A' , 'B')
/
```

Comment: Thanks but that is probably not right - both A and B are database owners with its own objects.

Comment: @Kalamro - your terminology is confusing.  There are no "database owners" in Oracle, there are only users.  A SCHEMA is just the collection of objects owned by a USER.  They are separate things but there is a one-to-one relationship between them: http://radiofreetooting.blogspot.com/2007/02/user-schema.html

Comment: Thank you. I am MSSQL user so I misunderstood the point. Also, the first query is enough for finding out ALL rights in the schema A?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly create sample users "user_a" and "user_b":

```
SQL> create user user_a identified by user_a default tablespace users temporary tablespace temp;
SQL> create user user_b identified by user_b default tablespace users temporary tablespace temp;
SQL> grant connect to user_a, user_b;
SQL> grant create session to user_a, user_b;
SQL> grant create table to user_a, user_b;
SQL> grant create view to user_a, user_b;
SQL> alter user user_a quota unlimited on users;
SQL> alter user user_b quota unlimited on users;
```

Now connect as USER_A and create sample objects:

```
SQL> conn user_a/user_a
Connected.
SQL> create table tbl_a(id number, text varchar2(200));
Table created.
SQL> create view view_a as select id, text from tbl_a;
View created.
```

Then connect as USER_B and create sample objects:

```
SQL> conn user_b/user_b
Connected.
SQL> create table tbl_b(id number, text varchar2(200));
Table created.
SQL> create view view_b as select id, text from tbl_b;
View created.
```

And finally connect back as USER_A a search grants for his table TBL_A:

```
SQL> conn user_a/user_a
Connected.
SQL> select count(1) from ALL_TAB_PRIVS where grantor = 'USER_A' and PRIVILEGE = 'SELECT' and GRANTEE = 'USER_B';
```

Out is:

```
  COUNT(1)
----------
         0
```

Now grant select on view VIEW_A for USER_B:

```
SQL> grant select on view_a to user_b;
Grant succeeded.
```

And again try search grants for USER_B to view object VIEW_A from USER_A:

```
SQL> select count(1) from ALL_TAB_PRIVS where grantor = 'USER_A' and PRIVILEGE = 'SELECT' and GRANTEE = 'USER_B';
```

And now result is:

```
  COUNT(1)
----------
         1
```

Comment: Sorry, the A and B owners are DB owners / schema owners.